Non-Hermiticity of the Dirac Hamiltonian in curved spacetime
In flat spacetime, Dirac fermions are classically described by the action
$$
S=\int d^Dx\;\bar\psi(x)\left(i\gamma^a\partial_a-m\right)\psi(x).
$$
One can generalize this to a general curved spacetime by introducing a covariant  derivative $\nabla_\mu$ constructed with a spin connection $\nabla_\mu\equiv\partial_\mu+\Gamma_\mu$, introducing curved spacetime gamma matrices $\underline{\gamma}^\mu=e^\mu_a\gamma^a$, where $e^\mu_a$ is a tetrad element, and modifying the integral measure by introducing $\sqrt{-g}$. Therefore, one arrives at
$$
S=\int d^Dx\sqrt{-g}\;\bar\psi(x)\left(i\underline{\gamma}^\mu(\partial_\mu+\Gamma_\mu)-m \right)\psi(x).
$$
One can straightforwardly obtain the Hamiltonian of the theory by means of a Legendre transform.
$$H=\int d^Dx\sqrt{-g}\;\bar\psi(x)\left(-i\underline\gamma^i\nabla_i-i\underline\gamma^0\Gamma_0+m\right)\psi(x), $$
where $\mu=i$ stands for spatial coordinates, while $\mu=0$ stands for the temporal coordinate.
It is well-known that this Hamiltonian is non-Hermitian (see eg. [1]), which is clearly a problem in order to implement unitary evolution and to obtain real energies. However, I have found different, inequivalent ways to deal with this problem. For example, in [1] the authors propose to modify the Hamiltonian by including a term that removes the non-Hermiticity,
$$H\rightarrow H'=H-i\frac{1}{2}\frac{\underline\gamma^0(x)\gamma^0}{g^{00}\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\sqrt{-g}\gamma^0\underline\gamma^0(x)).$$
This term removes the non-Hermiticity.
However, in other references (in my opinion, more numerous), the strategy is to rescale the spinor fields in some way dependent upon the specific spacetime, $$\psi(x)\rightarrow\Psi(x)=f(g)\psi(x),$$ such that the non-Hermitian term is removed, but also other effects, such as a global function multiplying the Hamiltonian, arises.
Both ways of proceeding remove the non-Hermitian terms, but yield different Hamiltonians, which leads to inequivalent time evolutions. Therefore, my question is: is this an ambiguity of QFT in curved spacetimes, or is there a unique correct way of correcting the non-Hermitian Hamiltonian?

REFERENCES
[1] Xing Huang and Leonard Parker, Phys. Rev. D 79, 024020 (2009).

Forget about the Hamiltonian. For starters, given that $\partial_\mu \underline{\gamma}^\mu \neq 0$, even your action $S=\int d^Dx\sqrt{-g};\bar\psi(x)\left(i\underline{\gamma}^\mu(\partial_\mu+\Gamma_\mu)-m \right)\psi(x)$ itself is NOT Hermitian, right? You have to write the action as $S=\int d^Dx\sqrt{-g};\bar\psi(x)\left(i\underline{\gamma}^\mu(\partial_\mu+\Gamma_\mu)-m \right)\psi(x)  + h.c.$

Yes, the action itself is not Hermitian. In fact, in the article that I mention, the Hamiltonian is obtained by casting the resulting e.o.m.s. into a Schrödinger-like form, and then they read out the Hamiltonian operator. Therefore, the non-Hermiticity is inherited from a non-Hermiticity in the action. However, I am not sure if the solution is as simple as adding the h.c., as I don't think it is the customary approach to remove this non-Hermiticity (in fact, Nakahara studies this in his book and I think he arrives to a more commplicated action, see eq. (7.229a') vs. (7.229a).

My take on this is that Hermiticity is necessary for probability conservation  but the conservation equation Dirac equation has nothing to do with probability, but rather with charge or particle number.  The case I have worked through is for  metrics of the form
$$
ds^2 = -dt^2+ g_{ij} dx^idx^j
$$
with time-dependent $g_{ij}$.
The associated  Dirac
equation is unambiguously
$$
i \partial_t \psi= (H- \frac  i2\partial_t\sqrt {-g})\psi,
$$
where $H$ is the usual Legendre-transform Hamiltonian. The   the extra term automatically arises from the $\omega_{0ij}$ spin connection and   serves to change the conservation of $J^\mu =\bar\psi\gamma^\mu \psi$  from
$$
\partial_\mu J^\mu \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \partial_\mu \sqrt{-g} J^\mu = \nabla_\mu J^\mu=0,
$$
which guarantees that charge is conserved.

Thanks for your answer! I have two questions:
(i) In your Dirac equation, is $H$ the flat-spacetime Hamiltonian?
(ii) However, I think that my problem with how one defines the Hermitian Hamiltonian is broader than how to define the Dirac equation. The Dirac equation is a classical e.o.m., and therefore is not affected, for example, by a global constant (or function) multiplying the Hamiltonian, because the Hamilton-Jacobi eqs. are insensitive to this. However, this constant plays a role when quantizing the theory, and is the big difference between the two approaches that I present.

H is, in general the curved-space Hamiltonian. My example was rather restricted beause I worked through that particular case last year  (in arXiv:2307.06811). I
am not multiplying the Lagrangian by a function, but just doing what I think to be standard stuff.
